# Is the life of a thread, created from a servlet, assured?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

Assuming that launching threads from a servlet is something not recommended, I'd like to know what can make this thread, created and launched from a servlet, to stop unexpectedly.

For example, reuse of the servlet thread can cause the child thread to be destroyed?.

I need clear arguments showing that the life of a thread from a servlet generated is not assured to the end, or reasoning to support otherwise.

I do not want a discussion, I want clear and definitive examples.

Comment: if you want a clear example, why don't you just simply make the thread print a counter value and try to reuse the servlet by yourself?

Comment: "SO is no place for discussions" - adopted from here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Gryzlov#cite_note-10

Answer (score 4):

Threads created from a servlet will not be terminated by the container (as long as the container is running), because of two reasons:

- The container does not have references to the threads created inside the servlets, therefore it cannot invoke e.g. `Thread.stop()` on them (Yes, this is a deprecated method and definitely not a good way of terminating threads, [more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)).
- Only the thread itself can know how to properly unlock the monitors that it has locked so forcing a thread termination will result in inconsistent state of the monitors.

Notes:

- This behavior is not covered by the Servlet specification so there is no guarantee how it will work on your web container.
- Servlets should not be spawning threads as this is the resource managed by the web container.

Comment: `Thread.stop()` is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, sure it is, it is a BAD way of stopping threads, the explanation is in reason 2.